# Query with JOIN on multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have this little query that is working fine:

```
SELECT * FROM Components AS T1
WHERE Cost=null or Cost=''
Order by Code
```

Now I need to grab also the filed "description" from other tables where code=code

```
SELECT * FROM Components AS T1
WHERE Cost=null or Cost=''

LEFT JOIN on Table_321 AS T2
where T1.Code=T2.Code

Order by Code
```

But it is giving me a sintax error around "LEFT" which I have not been able to solve and I am not sure if such JOIN is the correct way to get it. Some help indicating me the how to solve the problem will be really appreciated. Moreover, I have also another table "Table_621 from which I need to take the description. How can I add this second table in the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Components T1
LEFT JOIN Table_321 T2 ON T1.Code=T2.Code
LEFT JOIN Table3 T3 ON T3.Code = T1.Code
WHERE T1.Cost=null or T1.Cost=''
ORDER BY T1.Code
```

Comment: This is working. Thank you. As I mentiond in my question, I need to make also the same JOIN on another table. Do you mind to show me how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Components AS T1
LEFT JOIN Table_321 AS T2
ON T1.Code=T2.Code
WHERE Cost=null or Cost=''

Order by Code
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, this one s giving me error on "ON", sintax not correct

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that. You should probably look at SQL tutorial. :)

Answer (score 0):

Order by is ambiguous In below case:

```
SELECT * FROM Components T1
    LEFT JOIN Table_321 T2
    ON T1.Code=T2.Code
    WHERE T1.Cost=null or T1.Cost=''
    ORDER BY Code
```

try like this

```
SELECT * FROM Components T1
        LEFT JOIN Table_321 T2
        ON T1.Code=T2.Code
        WHERE T1.Cost=null or T1.Cost=''
        ORDER BY T2.Code --or T1.Code
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer which is of course correct. I accepted Jason answer becouse came first.